# List union implementation

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, set

I'm trying to implement `union` from the standard `Data.List` library. I know it's reinventing the wheel, but reimplementing functions is how I learn things. Any feedback at all would be helpful!

```
union' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union' [] _ = []
union' _ [] = []
union' xs ys = nub' $ xs ++ ys where 
    nub' [] = []
    nub' (x:xs)
        | not $ x `elem` xs = x : nub' xs
        | otherwise = nub' xs
```

This code works, but it strikes me as verbose. `union` is the opposite of `intersect`, which does not require a helper `where` statement:

```
intersect' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersect' [] _ = []
intersect' _ [] = []
intersect' (x:xs) list
    | x `elem` list = x : intersect' xs list
    | otherwise = intersect' xs list
```

How can I make my `union` function resemble the elegance of my `intersect` function?

Revision [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121317/haskell-union-list-implementation-pt-2)

Comment: I am glad you were able to clean up your code.  If you would like a review on the changes, please post another question rather than appending the new code to the current question.

Answer (score 3):

Your base cases are both invalid and unnecessary:

> ```
> union' [] _ = []
> union' _ [] = []
> ```

There isn't anything bad about using `where`, especially when you consider that `union'` needs no base cases.  Your question is, really, whether `union'` should be implemented using some kind of `nub` or not.  If you're [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) as an exercise, why wouldn't you want to reimplement `nub` as well?

The real question you should be asking is how to avoid `++`.

Comment: Please see my updates, iv turned your suggestions into a new solution. Do you have any more comments? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 4 → 3.

Comment: Revision: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121317/haskell-union-list-implementation-pt-2